# using linux command and gnu software inside a ruby script

Tags: shell-script, command, ruby

Can I use `ls` command or `wget` gnu software inside a Ruby script?
Actually, can I use Ruby instead of Bash , and use all of Linux commands and Gnu Software ?

Comment: actually , i love ruby and Gnu/Linux , but not bash ! . so i want to finding a solution for don't using bash.

Comment: Hi! Is your question "can I use Ruby as a shell instead of more typical shells like bash"? Or is it "can I replace my shell scripts with Ruby scripts"?

Comment: @dhag , my question is "can i use Ruby as s shell instead of more typical shells like bash "

Answer (score 1):

There are Unix shells written in many popular languages, Ruby
included. An example is [rush](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rush)
(also described at http://rush.heroku.com/, which, hilariously, has
misconfigured SSL). A few examples of its use, from the documentation:

> Count the number of classes in your project using bash:
>
> ```
> find myproj -name \*.rb | xargs grep '^\s*class' | wc -l
> ```
>
> In rush, this is:
>
> ```
> myproj['**/*.rb'].search(/^\s*class/).lines.size
> ```

It could be debated how practical this is as a Unix shell, but it may
be worth a try for a hard-core Ruby user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232/calling-shell-commands-from-ruby

If you don't like bash you can use python, there is also a program called iPython which emulate shell but using python syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
x = %x(your command goes here)
```

if you need the output of the command in a variable, or

```
system(your command goes here)
```

if you want the output of the command be displayed on the screen.